# Do I need to un-install aspnet mvc2 for vs2008 before installing vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I just grabbed vs2010 release from msdn and I wanted to find out if anyone had any issues installing this on a machine that had mvc2 installed already for use with vs2008.

Comment: What version of mvc2 do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTM for Visual Studio 2010 should be compatible with ASP.NET MVC 2.0 that is already installed on your computer, *provided you have the RTM version of ASP.NET MVC 2.0.*  If you have any other version of ASP.NET MVC, you need to uninstall it first.